# SQL - display from table groups of rows as columns

Tags: sql

I am trying to take range of codes in one column and display their results under one column per category.

Example of my table:

```
ID | TEST_NUM | RESULT | 
---+----------+--------+
1  |    R1    |   33   |
1  |    R2    |   31   |
1  |    C1    |   24   |
1  |    C2    |   19   |
```

by query from table above i am trying to get the next table:

```
ID | TEST_NUM OF R ONLY | R RESULTS | C RESULTS 
---+--------------------+-----------+----------
1  |    R1              |   33      |     24     
1  |    R2              |   31      |     19
```

Comment: How do you relate `R1` and `C1` (or `R2/C2`)? Are these values fixed or the might vary?

Comment: This looks like a bad data model. If you consider R1 and C1 related and R2 and C2, then the letter and the number should be in separate columns.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

String operations can vary by database.  I will assume yours supports `left()` and `right()` (which are easily represented by similar functions).

```
select id, max(test_num) as test_num,
       max(case when test_num like 'R%' then result end) as r_result,
       max(case when test_num like 'C%' then result end) as c_result
from t
group by id, right(test_num, 1)
```